# Как в Java сравнить 2 вещественных числа на равенство?

Tags: java, ieee-754

У меня есть 2 вещественных числа, например типа `double`. Я хочу их сравнить на равенство с заданной точность. Как правильно выполнять такое сравнение?

Пока в  голову приходит такой вариант:

```
double x, y;
...
public boolean isEqual(double x, double y, double eps){
    return Math.abs(x-y) < eps;
}
```

Кажется, что в `Java` должны быть встроенные способы сравнить 2 вещественных числа. Такие существуют?

Comment: ваш вариант самый правильный, метод только сделайте статическим и, возможно, напишите перегрузку со стандартным эпсилоном. и ещё возможно, можно написать другой метод, сравнивающий относительные отклонения вместо абсолютных

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще, это довольно интересный вопрос.

Да, в общем случае всегда рекомендуется использовать что-то вроде:

```
bool isEqual = fabs(a1 – a2) <= epsilon;
```

Но более интересный вопрос, какое значение для `epsilon` использовать.

К примеру, в C++ в **float.h** есть константа `FLT_EPSILON`, равная `1E-5`. Всё, можно такое же значение использовать, да?

Вполне, если числа большие. Но если у вас число в промежутке [0;1], то начинаются проблемы. Точность вычисления будет соизмерима с фактическим значением, что приведёт к тому, что на такое сравнение нельзя будет положиться.

## Относительный эпсилон

Для сравнения чисел можно руководствоваться правилом:

> Для сравнения a1 и a2 вычисляем diff = fabs(a1-a2). Если diff меньше
>   ,чем n% от max(abs(a1), abs(a2)), тогда a1 и a2 можно считать равными.

```
public static bool almostEqualRelative(float a, float b,
                         float maxRelDiff = FLT_EPSILON) {
    // находим разницу
    float diff = fabs(a - b);
    A = fabs(a);
    B = fabs(b);
    // находим большее
    float largest = (b > a) ? b : a;

    if (diff <= largest * maxRelDiff)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Более сложно и подробней про это можно почитать в [этой](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/) занятной статье.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать класс BigDecimal. Пример :

```
BigDecimal decimal = new 
BigDecimal("0.58499999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375");
BigDecimal decimal2 = new 
BigDecimal("0.58499999999999996447286321199499070644378662109374");

System.out.println(decimal.compareTo(decimal2));

Double x  = 0.58499999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375;
Double y = 0.58499999999999996447286321199499070644378662109374;

System.out.println(x>y);
```

Вывод:

- 1
- false

Comment: Сообщение было опубликовано в качестве ответа, но оно не содержит ответа на поставленный вопрос. Стоило разместить его комментарием.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря до какой точности вам надо сравнить.

Например (0.1 + 0.2) == 0.3 сравниваем до точности 0.00001:

- `Math.abs((a + b) - c) < 0.00001` возврат `boolean`

Answer (score 0):

2 Вещественных числа сравнивают с помощью метода Math.abs(), подставляя пороговое число, оно определяет насколько точное сравнение тебе нужно в конкретном случае (обычно это одна десятитысячная: `Math.abs(a - b) < 0.00001`

Сумму двух вещественных чисел сравнивают с третим вещественным числом таким же образом: `Math.abs(a + b - с) < 0.00001`

Comment: Зачем писать то, что автор уже привёл в вопросе?