# Что делать, если результат вычислений double дает лишнюю дробную часть?

Tags: java, double

Что делать, если результат вычислений double дает лишнюю дробную часть? Скажем должно получится число 2, а получается 1.999999996.

```
public class ComplexNumberTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ComplexNumber cn1 = new ComplexNumber(-5.1, 8.3);
        ComplexNumber cn2 = new ComplexNumber(-3.1, 4.8);
        System.out.println(cn1.sum(cn2));
        System.out.println(cn1.subtraction(cn2));
        System.out.println(cn1.multiplication(cn2));
        System.out.println(cn1.module());
    }
}

class ComplexNumber{
    private double realPart;
    private double imaginaryPart;
    
    
    public ComplexNumber(){}
    
    public ComplexNumber(double r){
        this.realPart = r;
    }
    
    public ComplexNumber(double r, double i){
        this.realPart = r;
        this.imaginaryPart = i;
    }
    
    public double getRealPart(){
        return this.realPart;
    }
    
    public void setRealPart(double r){
        this.realPart = r;
    }
    
    public double getImaginaryPart(){
        return this.imaginaryPart;
    }
    
    public void setImaginaryPart(double i){
        this.imaginaryPart = i;
    }
    
    public ComplexNumber sum(ComplexNumber that){
        ComplexNumber result = new ComplexNumber();
        result.setRealPart(this.getRealPart() + that.getRealPart());
        result.setImaginaryPart(this.getImaginaryPart() + that.getImaginaryPart());
        return result;
    }
    
    public ComplexNumber subtraction(ComplexNumber that){
        ComplexNumber result = new ComplexNumber();
        result.setRealPart(this.getRealPart() - that.getRealPart());
        result.setImaginaryPart(this.getImaginaryPart() - that.getImaginaryPart());
        return result;
    }
    
    public ComplexNumber multiplication(ComplexNumber that){
        ComplexNumber result = new ComplexNumber();
        result.setRealPart((this.getRealPart() * that.getRealPart()) - (this.getImaginaryPart() * that.getImaginaryPart()));
        result.setImaginaryPart((this.getRealPart() * that.getImaginaryPart()) + (that.getRealPart() * this.getImaginaryPart()));
        return result;
    }
    
    public Double module(){
        Double result = new Double(0);
        result = Math.sqrt((this.getRealPart() * this.getRealPart()) + (this.getImaginaryPart() * this.getImaginaryPart()));
       
       // Double tmp = this.getRealPart() > 0 ? this.getRealPart() : -this.getRealPart();
       // result.setRealPart(tmp);
        return result;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "{ " + this.getRealPart() + ", " + this.getImaginaryPart() + "}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Конкретнее. какие именно операции делаете для получения `2` ?

Comment: Вы можете сравнивать с учетом с учетом незначительной разницы, например, считать числа равными, если между ними разница 0.000001. Уже был такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749740/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-java-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-2-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)

Comment: Выполняю сложение, вычитание и умножение

Comment: Прошу же - конкретнее. Прям вот точный пример давайте, чтобы было на чем разбираться )  А то получается по типу "почему у меня получается 8, а не 9? Да кто вас знает, может потому что вы 4+4 складываете ))))"

Comment: @РусланМамедов дело осложняется еще тем, что автор вопроса лукавит, 1.999999996 не выглядит как погрешность записи double (там больше значащих цифр должно быть).

Comment: 8.3 и 4.8 в сумме дают 13.100000001

Comment: Потому что я не копировпл и вставлял, а написал случайное количестао чисел после запятой, оно примерно равно тому которое получается и общий смысл должен быть понятен

Comment: Пожалуйста не делайте так. Если вы задаете вопрос со случайными данными, то будьте готовы получить случайный ответ ))) Сейчас попробую найти вам ответ по 8,3+4,8.

Comment: Я выложил код, который дает такие кривые вычисления. Можно посмотреть там.

Comment: Вот, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста, это дубликат вашего вопроса по сути - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453

Answer (score 3):

В ответе на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE) описано почему именно такое поведение при операциях над числами с плавующей точкой, к коим относятся и `double`, как в вашем вопросе, и `float`.

Именно из-за такого особенностей операций с плавующей точкой нижеописанный код выведет `0.30000000000000004`.

```
double a = 0.1;
double b = 0.2;
System.out.println(a + b);
// Выведет: 0.30000000000000004
```

Что можно с этим сделать?

Вы можете заменить использование `double` на `BigDecimal`. Класс `BigDecimal` специально предназначен для представления десятичных дробей и для точных операций с ними.

Код ниже с использованием `BigDecimal` уже выведет ожидаемые `0.3`.

```
BigDecimal aBd = new BigDecimal("0.1");
BigDecimal bBd = new BigDecimal("0.2");
System.out.println(aBd.add(bBd));
// Выведет: 0.3
```

Comment: Вы отлично оформили ответ, но обычно на дубликаты без толку отвечать, их обычно быстро закрывают )

Comment: Я не считаю данный вопрос дубликатом ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453, потому что действительно тема одна и та же, но в нем не описано, что можно с этим сделать в Java.

Comment: Цитата из принятого ответа к тому вопросу: "Для вычислений с деньгами следует использовать специальные типы чисел, основанные на десятичной системе, если они доступны, например, Decimal в C#, BigDecimal в Java и т.п." Ну вы свой ответ не удаляйте если что, я ему плюс поставил. Просто не удивляйтесь, что вопрос скорее всего скоро закроют.

Answer (score 2):

> Что делать, если результат вычислений double дает лишнюю дробную часть? Скажем должно получится число 2, а получается 1.999999996.

1. Проверять вычисления по шагам и смотреть в чем у вас ошибка.
2. Учитывать особенности записи чисел с точкой и присущие им ограничения (как, например, ограниченную точность, и невозможность точного представления большинства чисел)

А вообще этот вопрос уже задавался и на него есть отличные ответы - [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой работают неправильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453)